# Where to find a list of packages at CTAN?

Tags: packages, ctan

I am looking for something similar to

http://www-sop.inria.fr/apics/latex/styles-eng.html
(but more recent than 2001)

i.e. a list of packages/styles on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) containing

```
package name - file name - version date - version - "provides" text
```

For example for `backref` this would be

```
hyperref - backref.sty - 2010/08/30 - v1.36 - Bibliographical back referencing
```

(possibly with linking to http:// ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ < package > and the corresponding < package >.tds.zip file, if this exists).

Does such a list (or something similar) exist (and where, of course)?

Comment: [The TeX Catalogue Online, Ctan Edition](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/catalogue.html)

Comment: @LeoLiu: OK, I can find the information there, but what about a concise list? Do I overlook some link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

with TeXLive you have a list of all installed packages/files which is under Linux in `.../texlive/2011/tlpkg/` saved as `texlive.tlpbd`. A typical entry for a package is like:

```
name pst-eucl
category Package
revision 24926
shortdesc Euclidian geometry with pstricks.
longdesc The pst-eucl package allow the drawing of Euclidean geometric
longdesc figures using TeX pstricks macros for specifying mathematical
longdesc constraints. It is thus possible to build point using common
longdesc transformations or intersections. The use of coordinates is
longdesc limited to points which controlled the figure.
containersize 11764
containermd5 bad06e593175f9d5fbf79b410a77eaae
doccontainersize 357672
doccontainermd5 f2be07b38b5d644172575dddfd4767fd
docfiles size=225
 texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-eucl/Changes
 texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-eucl/README details="Readme"
[... the file list ... ]
runfiles size=19
 texmf-dist/dvips/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.pro
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex
 texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.sty
catalogue-ctan /graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl
catalogue-date 2011-12-23 12:25:21 +0100
catalogue-license lppl
catalogue-version 1.42
```

Updates are listed as `texlive.tlpbd.<hash>`. You can use a simple script to grab the interesting lines.

Comment: +1, found it at \TeXlive2011\tlpkg\texlive.tlpdb under Windows.

Comment: while tex live should have nearly everything you need, there are some packages on ctan that aren't eligible for tex live because of restricted or uncertain licenses.  how to get a "simple" list of those?

Comment: @barbara: there is no complete list which describes the type of the files. There is only a complete file list: http://mirror.ctan.org/FILES.byname , which is not really helpful in finding all packages

Comment: i do know about `FILES.byname` and keep a recent copy here for quick reference (frequently used).  a supplementary list might be derivable from the catalogue (and would be useful), but i'm not the one to do it.  just thought that pointing out the limitations of tex live was worth a clarification.  (there are also a number of good packages that aren't even on ctan; i try to persuade a package author to post it whenever i find one, but am not always successful.)